# Can he be serious?

Tags: modal-verbs

a) *What **can** they be doing*?

b) ***Can** he be serious*?

What does "can" mean in sentences a) and b)? Can we replace it by "could"?

Comment: The answer to your questions depends on the context; could you provide more information?

Comment: a) I wonder what they are doing. b) Is it possible that he is serious?

Comment: @KateBunting, I think your paraphrases are very precise. Can I use "could" in a) and b) with those meanings?

Comment: Yes, you could use _could_, either to express a more hypothetical situation (What do you imagine they might be doing?) or simply in the past tense.

Comment: @KateBunting, Is this sentence possible: ***Could** he be serious?* in the sense of "**Is it possible that** he is serious?"

Comment: Yes, that is what my last comment was meant to tell you.